# Key ‘confirm_exercise’ was not defined. Path: ‘/forms/health_form’

Tags: rasa, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa-sdk

I am getting the error 'Key was not defined for the domain.yml file when I try to train my model.

I am trying to build a form and use RASA documentation as a guideline. I follow these articles for guidance - [how-to-build-your-first-rasa-form](https://rasa.com/blog/how-to-build-your-first-rasa-form/) and [updating-to-rasa-open-source-2-0/](https://rasa.com/blog/updating-to-rasa-open-source-2-0/).

I am not understanding where I should define the key. Initially, I thought to define it in slots, but it is already defined in slots, yet it gives me this error. I am using RASA 3.5

Please help me if anyone knows how to resolve this error. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could you pls share your domain file?

Comment: Another thing is that you followed the guide for Rasa 2.0 documents for your project but your installed Rasa is 3.X

Comment: That is right. I was referring to 2.0 documentation but was building in v3.5.